# How do I configure two sets of hosts (3 for QA and 3 for Prod) for deploying a distributed system using Spinnaker?

Tags: devops, spinnaker

I am using Spinnaker to deploy a 3-tier system to QA and then to Production. Configuration files in each of these systems point to others. If I bake in the configuration for QA in the AMI, then how do I change it while promoting to Prod? Is it 1) by having two different sets of AMIs - one for QA and one for Prod, or, 2) by having the AMIs with no configuration and then configure it (somehow) after deployment to change the configuration files?
What is recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define custom [AWS user data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-user-data-retrieval) for cluster at deploy time ( under advanced settings of the cluster configuration ). You can then retrieve this user data in your application. This will allow you to change these type of configurations.

At Netflix, we have a series of init scripts that are baked into the base image and provide a mechanism for extending custom startup ( init.d ) scripts via nebula / gradle. This usually sets values like NETFLIX_ENVIRONMENT that are well known and programmed against.

We also use a feature flipping mechanism via https://github.com/Netflix/archaius . This allows us to add properties that are external to the clusters but can be targeted towards them.

When it comes to secured credentials, the approach is outlined in this presentation, but essentially the images reach out to an external service that issues these type of creds. https://speakerdeck.com/bdpayne/key-management-in-aws-how-netflix-secures-sensitive-data-without-its-own-data-center

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling with similar problems myself in our company.
My solution was to create AMIs for specific purposes using a Packer script. This allows me to -
1. Configure the server as much as I can and then store those configurations in an AMI.
2. Easily change these configurations if the need arises.

Then, launching the AMI using an Ansible script, and make all the rest of the configurations on the specific instance.

In my case I chose creating different images for staging and production, but mostly because they differ greatly. If they were more alike I might have chosen using a single AMI for both.

The advantage Ansible gives you here is factoring your configurations, and including written once to both production and staging servers.